# Cómo obtener el último valor en un evento de "resize" en un panel?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un problema con una libreria que maneja un evento de resize de un panel, mientras hago el resize me va arrojando los valores correspondientes al nuevo tamaño del objeto, el problema está en que necesito guardar ese ultimo tamaño que quedó registrado, pero si adjunto el evento de "guardado" al cambio de la variable, estaria llamando muchas veces al evento de guardado y quiero evitar eso. Qué podría hacer para guardar ese último size que queda resitrado en la variable sin necesidad de llamar tantas veces el "guardar"?

Actualmente, si hago el resize, llama el evento por cada posicion comprendida entre la posicion inicial y la posicion final del panel. (pueden ser muchisimos valores)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el componente tiene un evento sizeChange que me permite obtener la posicion:

```
(sizeChange)="onPanelResizing($event)"
```

Luego yo emito este valor al componente padre que es donde necesito usar ese valor y posteriormente guardarlo

```
onPanelResizing(newSize: any) {
  this.newPanelSize.emit(newSize);
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cómo obtienes los valores que la biblioteca va arrojando?

Comment: En el mismo mensaje lo estoy mostrando. La libreria me proporciona una evento sizeChange que me regresa el valor del width. El problema es que mientras estoy cambiando el width del panel, se van generando valores distintos dependiendo de la posicion a donde agrande o achique el width del panel. Lo que quiero es que al momento de hacer el resize, guarde ese ultimo valor, pero no puedo hacerlo en ese mismo evento del resize porque haria muchos llamados al evento que guarda ese valor (un llamado por cada valor del width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes usar es una estrategia llamada `debounce` famosamente implementada en la librería **lodash** pero puedes implementar la propia tuya. Aún así para simplificarte la vida puedes usar esta.

**¿Qué hace la función debounce?**
Dada una función de entrada y un tiempo **x** si haces llamados múltiples llamados a la función y por lo menos no ha pasado el tiempo **x** desde el último intento de invocación la función en sí no se ejecutará.

Esta función es ampliamente usada en casos en donde se requiere mantener un buen rendimiento y evitar llamados inecesarios en una periodo corto de tiempo.

Información de debounce en lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

---

Acá un ejemplo de como funciona la función debounce con el evento scroll, para probarlo haz scroll dentro de las cajas de colores y observa con qué velocidad se actualiza el texto interno que muestra la posición del scroll.

```js
// No debounce
document.querySelector('#basic').addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  const textContainer = e.target.querySelector('.scroll-text');

  textContainer.innerText = `Scroll actual: ${parseInt(e.target.scrollTop, 10)}`;
});

// Debounced version
const debounceTime = 100; // Milliseconds

document.querySelector('#debounced').addEventListener('scroll', _.debounce((e) => {
  const textContainer = e.target.querySelector('.scroll-text');

  textContainer.innerText = `Scroll actual: ${parseInt(e.target.scrollTop, 10)}`;
}, debounceTime));
```

```css
.scroll-box {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #E59866;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.scroll-wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
}

.scroll-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

#debounced {
  background: #EC7063;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <div id="basic" class="scroll-box">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="scroll-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <div id="debounced" class="scroll-box">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="scroll-text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Si te fijas en el ejemplo con caja roja, verás que a diferencia de la caja naranja los eventos solo se registran un tiempo después de que dejas de hacer scroll a diferencia de la caja naranja en donde cada evento hace un llamado a actualizar la posición de scroll actual.

Este mismo principio lo puedes hacer con la función de resize que le pasas al event listener, es importante tener en cuenta que `debounce` retorna una función nueva y es esta nueva función la que le debes pasar al listener.